# Regex Matching Help

Tags: regex

```
two<div
class="blogger-post-footer"><img
width='1' height='1'
src='https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/tracker/4997742813462440000-8247376481926663915?l=isthereanyurlnamesleft.blogspot.com'
alt='' /></div>
```

I need to match from `<div` to `</div>`

Comment: What regex have you tried by yourself?

Comment: To be clear, a regex is not the right solution to this problem.

Comment: I am curious why you say it is not the right answer. I feel like I should be able to pull this post from Blogger without getting the tracker link injected in.

Comment: Anyone who atempts to learn regex tries inadvertently to apply it some sort of HTML parsing sooner or later. Regex is simply ill equipped for that kind of work. It's primarily for pattern matching and what your matching against (and given the provided answers) revolve around lazy (as opposed to greedy) matches. The problem with this regex approach (albeit that it works) is that there's no semantic analysis here, what so ever here. That the `</div>` is the right match here is pure luck (no matter how probable that match is).

Comment: Also, you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I have to agree with you that this is a naive approach but for the simple context I am in this is definitely an appropriate hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(<div.*?<\/div>)`. In the first backreference/group you get the match from `<div` to `</div>`.

You must use the /s flag (or an equivalent for the language you use) with this regex to let the . match newlines. [Documentation about /s says:](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

> To simplify multi-line substitutions, the "." character never matches a newline unless you use the /s modifier, which in effect tells Perl to pretend the string is a single line--even if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
    <(div*)\b[^>]*>((.|\n)*?)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below:

```
<div.*?</div>
```

Be sure to have `DOTALL` or `SINGLELINE` mode.

> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE
>   COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
>   * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO,  * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR  * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. 
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER
>   OR  * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
>   * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,  *
>   PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
>   SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR  *
>   PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
>   HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF  *
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
>   LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING  *
>   NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
>   ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS  *
>   SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
>   POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Above message for: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: But with option dot match newline, which depends on the regex engine you use.

Comment: @reeaal - hello, why the downvote? I just forgot to mention it.

Comment: you did not really post a gnu license for your answer?

Comment: @reeaal - `IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE` is what I wanted, not really a license :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <(?:([a-zA-Z\?][\w:\-]*)(\s(?:\s*[a-zA-Z][\w:\-]*(?:\s*=(?:\s*"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|\s*'(?:\\'|[^'])*'|[^\s>]+))?)*)?(\s*[\/\?]?)|\/([a-zA-Z][\w:\-]*)\s*|!--((?:[^\-]|-(?!->))*)--|!\[CDATA\[((?:[^\]]|\](?!\]>))*)\]\])>
```

this a template for extract any html brought from http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: slightly oversized for that problem :)

Comment: I agree it is oversized but it may help in another big issue.